# "No whitelist configured...". But thats not true. <whitelist> defined in Symfony app\phpunit.xml.dist. (This error occur only in Netbeans, not in cmd)

Tags: symfony, netbeans, phpunit

(I'm beginner in PHPUnit)

In Netbeans I try to code-coverage PHPUnit in Symfony2.8 project, but it throws error:

```
"C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\bin\phpunit.bat" "--colors" "--log-junit" "C:\Users\chiny\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-log.xml" "--coverage-clover" "C:\Users\chiny\AppData\Local\Temp\nb-phpunit-coverage.xml" "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.1\php\phpunit\NetBeansSuite.php" "--" "--run=C:\wamp\www\treningPHPUnitSymfony2.8\src\TreningBundle\Tests\Utils\CalculatorTest.php"
PHPUnit 5.3.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Error:         No whitelist configured, no code coverage will be generated

................I                                                17 / 17 (100%)

Time: 531 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 17, Assertions: 16, Incomplete: 1.
Done.
```

But i have Symfony default app\phpunit.xml.dist with `<whitelist>` defined :

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.8/phpunit.xsd"
         backupGlobals="false"
         colors="true"
         bootstrap="autoload.php"
>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="-1" />
        <!--
            <server name="KERNEL_DIR" value="/path/to/your/app/" />
        -->
    </php>

    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Project Test Suite">
            <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory>../src</directory>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Resources</directory>
                <directory>../src/*/Bundle/*Bundle/Tests</directory>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

I got:
Symfony2.8, PHPUnit5.3.4, Netbeans 8.1

---

edit

But in windows console command
`phpunit -c app/ src/TreningBundle/ --coverage-html=cov/` works great, generate coverage.

Comment: I see the [Symfony2.8 testing docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/testing.html) show "../lib" as the directory. I'm using 3.x and it shows "src/"

Comment: @AlvinBunk what is the conclusion?

Comment: I was just trying to be helpful. Not certain what the workaround is. Sebastian created phpunit, so you can maybe ask him.

Comment: @AlvinBunk it was not my intention to be rude. Just courious what you mean.

Comment: No offense taken. You can upvote me if you think it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: how could it be helpful? (now i'm rude)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the "No whitelist configured, no code coverage will be generated" message is also printed when the whitelist configuration is invalid, see https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/2049 for details.

Comment: anyway my test file `project_directory\src\TreningBundle\Tests\Utils\CalculatorTest.php` is inside `src` as pointed in `<whitelist>` inside `project_directory\app\phpunit.xml.dis`. So I don't get it.

Comment: I just noticed that this error occur only in Netbeans, not in cmd, so this has nothing to do with PHPUnit.